# Can I use python structured unpacking to do general type checking?

Tags: python, decorator, metaprogramming, matching

I am reading that Python matching can do type-checking.

```
def sum_two_integers(num1, num2):
    match num1, num2:
        case int(num1), int(num2):
            return num1 + num2
        case _:    # Wrong type
```

Is it possible to write a decorator that reads the function arguments' annotations and wraps any function with some matching to do strict run-time type checking?

I would like to do something along the lines of:

```
def my_checker(func):
   def wrapper(*args):
      for ((name, annotation), arg) in zip(func.__annotations__.items(), args):
           match arg:
              case (annotation??):
                  pass
              case _:
                  raise BadType
      func(*args)
   return wrapper


@my_checker
def some_func(...):
   ...
```

The annotation is `<class 'int'>`. How can I use it in the match?

Are there any libraries already doing this? This is related, but doesn't use annotations.
[Python: type checking decorator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36879932/python-type-checking-decorator). (Also, yes I know type-checking isn't Pythonic).

Comment: Did you look at [Pydantic](https://docs.pydantic.dev)?

Comment: The [@validate_arguments](https://docs.pydantic.dev/usage/validation_decorator/) decorator, although beta, does what you are looking for.